# How do I load an audio clip and get spectrum data of entire song before even starting the game

Tags: unity-game-engine, fft

I have this guitar hero style of game that I'm making on unity, and right now I need to find a way to place the notes down. In order to do this, I want to analyze the song's frequency samples. I'm currently able to analyze it in real-time but, I want to be able to see all of it before I even press play. Somewhat like a de-bugger. Is this possible?

Right now, I have it so it runs in real-time. But it's hard to get any information from the samples because it's so fast and it just gets reset after I restart my game.

```c#
//Listen to the audio source every frame and get a sample
[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class AudioPeer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource audioSource;
    //Will split 20 thousand hertz into 512 sameples/ subbass = 0/ 20k hertz = 512
    public static float[] audioSamples = new float[1024];
    //float[] frequencyBand = new float[8];


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        MakeFrequencyBand();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        GetSpectrumAudioSource();
    }

    void GetSpectrumAudioSource()
    {
        audioSource.GetSpectrumData(audioSamples, 0,FFTWindow.BlackmanHarris );
```

Comment: What do you mean `before starting the game` .. how should code be executed if you didn't start the app yet?

Comment: [This](https://forum.unity.com/threads/fft-same-data-consistently.431341/#post-2791755) might help

Comment: and [this one as wel](https://answers.unity.com/questions/974565/how-to-do-a-fft-in-unity.html)

Answer (score -1):

If you have your music known in advance (as in its not generative), you can do all the FFT calculations in advance, aka record output of the realtime analysis beforehand, save it to a file (i.e. a json file), and load it up when you load the music up. This way you don't depend on the current playhead position when grabbing fft results as you can grab them 'into the future', or average across few frames without introducing a latency that's pretty much always there if you just analyze via the AudioListener.GetSpectrumData in realtime